# Kivy FileChooserListView: how to disable opening directory and only use the expand function

Tags: python, kivy

I am developing a simple app with Kivy (version 2.1.0, on Python 3.8). Within such app, I have a `FileChooserListView` widget, added to a layout programmatically (I'm not using any .kv file), as follows:

```
self.new_file_chooser = FileChooserListView(
    size_hint=(0.9, 0.35),
    pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5}
)
self.my_layout.add_widget(self.new_file_chooser)
```

This produces something like this:

[image: FileChooserListView]

When shown, it allows me to explore the directories in two possible ways:

1. by clicking on the little arrows on the left side of each directory name, which expands the content:

[image: FileChooserListView - expand]

2. by clicking on the directory name, which changes the `path` attribute of the `FileChooserListView` object, and shows me a "..\" item on top, followed by the directory's contents (i.e. list of directories and files):

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to only enable the expand option, while disabling the second one, i.e. the possibility of clicking on the directory name.

Comment: first  I would check [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html) - it is based on [FileChooserController](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController) and it has `dirselect` which seems interesting. Maybe it can resolve your problem.

Comment: next I would check [source code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/filechooser.py#L914) - it based on [FileChooserController](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/filechooser.py#L306) and it has function [enter_subsubselect](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/filechooser.py#L904) which seems interesting. Maybe if you create own class with empty `enter_subsubselect` then it will work.

Comment: If I understand correctly, direselect only allows to enable o disable the possibility selecy folders, instead of only selects files. The enter_subsubselect seeems interesting, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by creating a new class based on `FileChooserListView`, and disabling the `open_entry` method:

```
class MyFileChooserListView(FileChooserListView):
    def open_entry(self, entry):
        return


self.new_file_chooser = MyFileChooserListView(
    size_hint=(0.9, 0.35),
    pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5}
)
self.my_layout.add_widget(self.new_file_chooser)
```

This completely disables any tap or double-tap interaction on the entry, while keeping the possibility of expanding the directory tree.